# Limit gas in brownie automated tests

Tags: testing, brownie

I have create a brownie project with automated tests according to this documentation:

https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/testing-contracts-brownie.html#writing-a-basic-test

Here is an example:

```
def test_set(storage_contract, accounts):
    storage_contract.set(10, {'from': accounts[0]})
    ...
```

As you can see, this line sends a transaction (calling set function). What i want to do is to limit gas units for this transaction.

Is there a way to do that just for this transaction ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter is a dictionary with the transactions parameters, see the [documentation](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core-contracts.html#transaction-parameters) for other fields you can include.

```
def test_set(storage_contract, accounts):
    storage_contract.set(10, {'from': accounts[0], 'gas_limit': 100000})
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and is there a way to say account[0] has only 1 ether in his balance ?

Comment: How can i handle "base fee exceeds gas limit" in automated tests with brownie ?

Comment: @Bob5421 For 1/ that parameters are transactions properties you cannot change an account balance from there. 2/ the error message says that the limit set is higher than the block limit in the client used (ganache, geth, infura, etc). If the block limit is 10M you cannot set limit to 20M.

Comment: For this error message, i want to catch this error message in my test scenario

Comment: @Bob5421 It is better to ask about the "base fee" error message in a new question. I don't know enough brownie to answer it.